# The equivalence of two different CNF logical formulas - complexity

Tags: logic

> We have two different logical formulas (ψ and ϕ). Is there a quick way
>   to prove that if the formulas are equivalent (or not)? (if the formula
>   ψ is unsat also a formula ϕ is unsat (in SAT problem))

Pre question: [The equivalence of two different CNF logical formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081508/the-equivalence-of-two-different-cnf-logical-formulas)

**The current question:** Is there a way to do it in polynomial time? (by the number of variables)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about propositional logic, we know that it can be in in non-polynomial time, but whether it can be done in polynomial time is exactly the question as to whether $P = NP$